# org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException: data exception: string data, right truncation; table:

Tags: hibernate, hsqldb

I migrated from HSQLDB 1.8.0 to 2.3.4.
After running BDUnit:beforeTestMethod

```
@BeforeMethod(groups = "integration-hibernate")
public void beforeTestMethod() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("beforeTestMethod");
    prepareSettings();
    for (DatabaseOperation op : beforeTestOperations) {
        op.execute(getConnection(), dataSet);
    }
}
```

I get:

```
data exception: string data, right truncation; table: BID column: IS_SUCCESSFUL

org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
```

Hibernate mapping for BID table:

```
<property name="successful"
              column="IS_SUCCESSFUL"
              type="true_false"
              not-null="true"/>
```

The dataset to fill the table for testing:

```
<BID
    BID_ID                  ="1"
    BID_AMOUNT              ="100"
    BID_AMOUNT_CURRENCY     ="USD"
    IS_SUCCESSFUL           ="false"
    ITEM_ID                 ="1"
    BIDDER_ID               ="1"
    BID_POSITION            ="0"
    CREATED                 ="2006-09-23 13:46:00"
/>

<BID
    BID_ID                  ="2"
    BID_AMOUNT              ="124"
    BID_AMOUNT_CURRENCY     ="USD"
    IS_SUCCESSFUL           ="true"
    ITEM_ID                 ="1"
    BIDDER_ID               ="1"
    BID_POSITION            ="1"
    CREATED                 ="2006-09-23 13:47:00"
/>
```

Is the boolean type changed in the new HSQLdb version? In the database the field is a character with length 1.

Answer (score 0):

Some things changed in 2.x, as fredt says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7582789/2387977).

Try to use 1 or 0 instead of `true` and `false`.

I'm not familiar with the way you are filling the test (with XML), but be sure that you are not passing a String to the boolean column.

In old versions of Hsqldb, you could pass **'0'** (string) and works. But in the most recent versions, you need to pass **0** (primitive number). Maybe you are passing **'true'** (string) instead of **true** (primitive boolean).